# REST API Gateway to External API Gateway communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS and I have an API gateway and this API gateway calls a application load balancer inside a public subnet. If i have to call and external API gateway from my API gateway, what can be my approach?

In order to call the application load balancer, in my API gateway i defined x-amazon-apigateway-integration and using a connectionType as VPC Link i was able to call the application load balancer, but what approach can i follow in i want to call and external api gateway instead.